# Is there a way to get a key press as easily as getting a mouse location

Tags: java, keylistener

Hello i was wondering if there was any easy way to make a KeyStroke recorder like a mouse recorder. This is what I have so far and i just added in the Key finder to try and assist you in what I mean. I have looked into KeyBinds and KeyListeners but I cannot get either to work.

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Mousefinder {


    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        while(true){
            Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            //^ works 
            Key key = KeyCode.getKeyinfo().getKeyPressed();
            //^ does not work
            double x = point.getX();

            double y = point.getY();

            System.out.println(x + " " + y);

            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, here is good example of keylistener:
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: @Sk1X1 Where is a good example?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need a listener to read keyPressed or keyReleased.

Comment: The mouse is a consistent thing with obtainable properties- keys, on the other hand, are more reactionary. What are you trying to do? Just record all the keys pressed?

Comment: This may help... http://forum.codecall.net/topic/59389-how-to-create-a-keylogger-in-java/

Comment: Please **don't** use KeyListeners, use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.

Comment: Where do `KeyCode` and `Key` come from? `java.awt.Toolkit#addAWTEventListener` may help.

Answer (score 1):

See [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for some ideas.